# Unable to use ternary operator (?) in TypeScript (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Im currently trying to setup a ternary operator condition in my onClick event in Next.js.
But im getting an error saying my condition is returning nothing. Please help...

[image]

[image]

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Answer (score 2):

The `onClick` handler expects a *function*, not a *function call*. Just add an arrow function that calls the *alert*.

```
onClick={... ? () => alert('...') : addToCardList};
```

Answer (score 0):

You correctly included the addToCart as a function by not calling it.

The problem is that you did not do the same for alert. Your alert is called while rendering, so you are trying to set the onClick function to the return of the alert call.

Replace `alert("aaaaa")` with `() => alert("aaaaaa")` to wrap it in a function